# Efficient way to convert flat data into nested group in C#

Tags: c#, performance, linq, nested

I have a task to convert flat data into double nested groups in C#.

I got it done, but it looks ugly. I am wondering if anyone could help me to point out how to make it more efficiently. Thank you in advance!

The data looks like (not the exact data and classes):

```
classFlatData = [{Class: Class1, Group: Group1, StudentName: Student1, StudentAge: 17},
                 {Class: Class1, Group: Group2, StudentName: Student2, StudentAge: 17}, 
                 {Class: Class2, Group: Group1, StudentName: Student3, StudentAge: 17},
                 {Class: Class2, Group: Group1, StudentName: Student4, StudentAge: 18}]
```

and the output should be something like:

```
classData = [{Class:Class1, 
              ClassStudentCount:2, 
              Groups:[{Group:Group1, 
                       GroupStudentCount:1, 
                       Students:[{StudentName: Student1, StudentAge:17},
                      {Group:Group2, 
                       GroupStudentCount:1, 
                       Students:[{StudentName: Student2, StudentAge:17}]}
                       ]
              },
            {Class:Class2, 
              ClassStudentCount:2, 
              Groups:[{Group:Group1, 
                       GroupStudentCount:2, 
                       Students:[{StudentName: Student3, StudentAge:17},
                                 {StudentName: Student4, StudentAge:18}]}
                      ]
              }]
```

The OUTPUT C# classes:

```
public class ClassModel
{
    public string Class {get;set}
    public int ClassStudentCount {get;set;}
    public List<GroupModel> Groups {get;set;}
}

public class GroupModel
{
   public string Class {get;set;}
   public string Group {get;set;}
   public int    GroupStudentCount {get;set;}
   public List<Student> Students {get;set}
}

public class StudentModel
{
   public string StudentName {get;set;}
   public int    StudentAge {get;set;}
}
```

So I tried something like the following: it works, but I am wondering if anyone has a better nice looking more efficient solution, please help me, let me know. Thank you so much!

```
var groupData = from d in classFlatData
                group d by new {d.Class, d.Group} into group
                select new GroupModel
                {
                  Class = group.Key.Class,
                  Group = group.Key.Group,
                  GroupStudentCount = group.Count(),
                  Students = group.Where(g => g.Class == group.Key.Class && g.Group == group.Key.Group).Select(s => new StudentModel(){
                                            StudentName = s.StudentName,
                                            StudentAge = s.StudentAge
                                           }).ToList()
                 };

var classData = from g in groupData
                group g by new {g.Class} into classes
                select new ClassModel()
                {
                  Class = classes.Key.Class,
                  ClassStudentCount = classes.Where(g => g.Class == classes.Key.Class).Select(g => g.GroupStudentCount).ToList().Sum(),
                  Groups =  classes.Where( g => g.Class == classes.Key.Class).ToList()
                }
```

I am thinking, is there a way to make it one process, instead of two parts now..

And is there a way to loop less and more efficiently?

Thank you so much

Comment: To me, I think it's totally fine or even recommended to split such kind of logic as it improves readability. Otherwise,  other team members will curse you if you make it really hard to understand in one big query.

Comment: FYI, this type of questions belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplified a little bit. You do not need filter already grouped records by it's key. Also aggregations can be made more optimal.

```cs
var groupData = 
    from d in classFlatData
    group d by new { d.Class, d.Group } into group
    select new GroupModel
    {
        Class = group.Key.Class,
        Group = group.Key.Group,
        GroupStudentCount = group.Count(),
        Students = group
            .Select(s => new StudentModel()
            {
                StudentName = s.StudentName,
                StudentAge = s.StudentAge
            })
            .ToList()
        };

var classData = 
    from g in groupData
    group g by new { g.Class } into classes
    select new ClassModel()
    {
        Class = classes.Key.Class,
        ClassStudentCount = classes.Sum(x => x.GroupStudentCount),
        Groups = classes.ToList()
    };
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help! I really learned a lot from you! I just googled how to accept answer and marked it :) Thanks Again!